# erlang distribution

Tags: probability

I think this is an erlang distribution problem but i'm not sure.

A fisher expects to catch a fish every 25 minutes.

What is the probability that she will need to wait 2 hours to catch 4 fish?

What is the probability that she will need to wait between 3 and 5 hours to catch 8 fish?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Clarification/Hint:**
I believe you can model the waiting time of a fish (catching a fish) as an exponential distribution with mean $25$ minutes. I think you would know that the sum of independent exponential waiting times follows a gamma (Erlang) distribution $T$.

Then let $T_i$ denote the $i$th waiting time. The problems become

1. $P(T_4>2\text{ hrs})$
2. $P(3\text{ hrs}<T_8<5 \text{ hrs})$

Comment: So i use the CDF for erlang: $$1- (e^(-k \theta x)(k(\theta)x)i)/i! $$ ?

Comment: @Mike I believe, you did not copy that correctly, but yes, you could use the cdf. That is one approach for part 1. For part 2, I would use the differenece of cdfs.

Comment: ok how do I calculate the CDF?  for the first one do I use k=4 $\theta$= 25 x=120 and calculate for i = 0,1, and 2 then add them together?  Sorry I haven't done probabilities in a while.  Im a computer science major and need them for simulation...

Comment: @Mike Yes, the typical formula for the cdf is $$1-e^{-\lambda x}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!}$$ where $r$ is the number of arrivals and $\lambda$ is the rate. So there is some adding up to do.

Comment: This is the formula I have: $$1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{e^(-k\theta x)*(k\theta x)^i)}{i!}$$

Comment: @Mike I doubt the are the same, maybe. Where did you get this? I got mine from a text book, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) seems to agree.

Comment: http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~lipschultz/cs1538/probability_hints.pdf the last page of this pdf

Comment: @Mike That's so strange, I've never heard of "rate of all events" before. And it's particularly useless since it doesn't point it out in the example. Since it does agree with the notation that $\lambda$ is the rate (in the example), I would stick with what I wrote. But if you want, you can wait for some else with more experience to chime in, or ask an instructor.

Comment: ok thanks for the help